# API for autopilot

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie at using API's. Because of my work, I have to learn to use Autopilothq. There is also an API for this which is in JavaScript:

http://developers.autopilothq.com/

But my question is basically, how do I implement all these functions? Do I have to make a administration site, where I implement these functions, or is it often in the online program itself they are called from?

For example, in the console of their site [Autopilot](https://autopilothq.com/customers.html), I can type the following:

```
var sessionId = AutopilotAnywhere.sessionId;
sessionId;
```

Then I get a 24 digit number. That number can be attached to a contact_id. But how do I execute this line of code on a site? Should I simply make a JS file and make my functions in here, then call the script from the head tag?

Updated question:
[image: Image on JavaScript]

Comment: The Autopilot API doesn't seem to be in JavaScript, it's REST.

Comment: Thank you. I could just see on the this link: http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/#reference/api-methods/bulk-add-contacts/bulk-add-contacts that you could make javascript calls. Is it the same principle that I have to make a script on the site, or?

Comment: I don't see where you can make JavaScript calls on that page...

Comment: This seems like a bit of a broad question.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but I just updated my question with a screenshot of it. But if we put that aside, and focus on how I implement these functions. Should I make scripts on the site, or how is it?

Comment: If I narrow the question down then. Should I make a js file and make the functions I want, or is it not that way the API function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript to access their API, you create a HTML document that contains a JavaScript script which does a [XMLHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) (Ajax) request to their [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services)-API with some code like the one from the example in your screenshot.

You need to specify your private API key (it acts as a kind of username and password in one thing) to allow the script access to your account. Then you create a request body and use a HTTP method to send your request (see [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)). The API then returns a JSON encoded string (or some error) that you can work with in your script.

So yes, basically you can create an administrative website that implements some functionality to make changes to your account (or whatever the API allows you to do). But an API allows you much more as it can be used with almost any programming language, so you could also create a native mobile or desktop app. You could also allow users to do something like [unsubscribe themselves](http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/#reference/api-methods/unsubscribe-contact/unsubscribe-contact) if the API allows you to create API keys with certain restrictions (i.e. only allow the unsubscribe action with the key that the user uses).

Keep in mind to not expose your API key. If you create a website to work with the API, make sure to not store the key in your script as everyone can view the source file. Instead you can either provide the key via PHP after some successful login only or have a look at server-side JavaScript (e.g. Node.js) or think of something else.

Comment: +1 for alerting the user to hide his/her API key from users. A common mistake for newbies who leave their credentials in code for everyone to see.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer here. That really helped me a lot. I am gonna try to make an admin site, with some javascript and also the REST. Often it wonders me why there is not some examples on how to use the API. Fx the section: "Finding the session id with javascript in the browser": "docs.autopilot.apiary.io/#reference/api-methods/…;. I feel that I have to guess a little bit here. But okay, copy/pasting is not a good way either. Thank you a lot :)